# How can I select the newest 40 records into a temp table?

Tags: select, subquery, sybase, sap-ase, correlated-subquery

I would like to get the latest 40 records into a temp table, something like this:

```
SELECT * INTO #MY_TEMP
FROM
  (
    SELECT TOP 40 *
    FROM SOME_TABLE
    ORDER BY RECORD_DATE DESC
  )
```

However I am getting an error:
An ORDER BY clause is not allowed in a derived table.

I saw a few workarounds mentioned on other postings, involving TOP PERCENT, but my select already uses a TOP and it is not working.

How can I get these records into my temp table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use `ORDER BY` in subselect statements. Instead remove the subselect. Your SQL should look like this:

```
SELECT TOP 40 * INTO #MY_TEMP
FROM SOME_TABLE
ORDER BY RECORD_DATE DESC
```